# Error: String indicies must be integers, list of dictionaries within a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each key holds a list of dictionaries.

It looks something like:

```
my_dict = {"op1": varient_dict[0], varient_dict[1], varient_dict[2]..., "op2": varient_dict[0]...}
where varient_dict = {"length":0, "color":0...}
```

I want to loop over the values in the nested dictionaries to find the greatest value (then store it in a second dictionary)

So far I have tried:

```
for  key in mydict:
    for varient_dict in key:
        if varient_dict["length"] > stats_dict[key]["max length"]:
            varient_dict["max length"] = stats_dict[key]["length"]
```

I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I believe I am calling the nested values in the dictionaries incorrectly? Or I am not iterating over the list correctly? Is there a better way to do this? (sorry if it looks terrible, I am a huge novice)

Thank you.

Comment: Clearly something is not a dict.. :-)

Comment: Your definition of `my_dict` is incorrect on several levels, and is obviously not the real code. Please provide a real example that we can reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

`for varient_dict in key:` iterates over the individual characters in `key`. You probably want to do `for varient_dict in mydict[key]`.

You could also just use `.items()`:

```
for key, varient_dict in mydict.items():
    if varient_dict["length"] > stats_dict[key]["max length"]:
        varient_dict["max length"] = stats_dict[key]["length"]
```

Comment: Hmm, okay I understand what you're saying about the incorrect iteration. However, I tried your suggestion and I still have the same error..In case it wasn't clear, for each key in my_dict, I have stored a list of more dictionaries. Am I referring to the nested dictionaries incorrectly?

Comment: @user2586260: What does `stats_dict` contain?

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over *keys*, not values:

```
for  key in mydict:
    for varient_dict in key:
```

Loop over the values instead:

```
for  key in mydict:
    for varient_dict in mydict[key]:
```

or loop over the `.iteritems()` results:

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    for varient_dict in value:
```

Your code loops over the individual characters of each key instead, so `varient_dict["length"]` indexes a string.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
for varient_dict in key:
```

Instead, you want to do this:

```
for varient_dict in mydict[key]:
```

In your version, you iterate over the single characters of the keys in `mydict` which you apparently don't want to do. That's what causes the error.